# Lock in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am making async calls to the server in a loop. Obviously ,it creates a race condition. Here is the code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  this.service.execute(arr[i]).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(response => {

    this.updateData(response); // Avoid race-condition here
  }, error => {
    //
  });
}
```

I need a mechanism to avoid race-condition. But at the same time I do not want to chain async calls (I want them to work in parallel, only `updateData` function call should be sync.). Here is a sample how my code would look like if I could use Python-like lock mechanism:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  this.service.execute(arr[i]).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(response => {
    // Assume lock is defined
    this.lock.acquire();
    this.updateData(response); // Avoid race-condition here
    this.lock.release();

  }, error => {
    //
  });
}
```

As clearly seen from above code, only the calls of `updateData` are waiting for each other, not async calls made to the server. Is it possible to achieve something like that in Javascript, if so how can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `Promise.all()` it accepts an array of promises and resolves/rejects only when all the promieses in the array have resolved or failed

Comment: But it still executes a couple of functions at the same time which is what I want to avoid

Comment: There is no built-in feature I know of which does it.
My first approach would be class for managing the locks.
A quick search brought me to [async-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-lock). Maybe thats what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javascript execution is always single-threaded](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/javascript-single-threaded/), so unless your `updateData` function contains async calls itself, there is no race condition.

Comment: It does not contain any async calls. Does that mean I can safely call the same function from different environments?

Comment: It depends what you mean by different environments. If they're all happening inside the same program/webpage/script, then yes.